# Add required attribute based on selected <select> value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a `<select>` with two options and an `<input>`. By default the `<input>` isn't required to submit the form. When the selected option from `<select>` has a value of `pizza` I want to add the `required` attribute to the `<input>`. I also want it removed if the user switches to the other `<select>` option.

```js
$(function() {
  var paymentType = $("#paymentType option:selected").val();
  if (paymentType == 'pizza') {
    $("firstName").prop('required', true);
  } else {
    $("firstName").prop('required', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="paymentType" name="paymentType" required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select Payment Type</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="highFive">High Five</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `select` a `change` handler, and also, to use the proper selector for `firstName` (put `#` in front to select the `id`):

```js
$("#paymentType").on('change', function() {
  const paymentType = this.value;
  if (paymentType == 'pizza') {
    $("#firstName").prop('required', true);
  } else {
    $("#firstName").prop('required', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="paymentType" name="paymentType" required>
    <option value="" hidden>Select Payment Type</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="highFive">High Five</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```